# How to get these files back?

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery

I ran the `rm -rf /` command on my kubuntu system and i ended all losing everything on my system.

I've seen several data recovery tools like foremost and testdisk but they all talk about running it from a live cd and getting the files from the existing partitions that are still there, but in my case i formatted my whole system and deleted the existing partitions and installed ubuntu afresh.

So is `foremost` or `testdisk` going to work since there is no partition again, if yes please post the steps, if no can you guys show me another alternative to scan the whole hard disk and find some of the lost files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: **Stop using the Drive!**

Step 2: Boot up using LiveCD/USB

Step 3: Install [TestDisk](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/testdisk/) to the live session using Software Centre

Step 4: Follow this guide to [recover your partition](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step). Pay particular attention to step 10. I think that might work for you.

Comment: ok, will try that

Comment: How did you get on?

Comment: i've been able to get some files back but the filenames are scattered like "file001.jpg, file002.jpg" but it's better than nothing

Comment: Yeah, a similar thing happened to me a few years back but on a USB that was plugged into the back of the computer. It got formatted during a full system wipe and I didn't realise till after. Same thing happened. I got some of the files back, but not the correct names and some other files that didn't seem to point to anything.