# How to find Ubuntu which is already installed?

Tags: dual-boot

How to find Ubuntu which is already installed, I have dual operating system in my COMPUTER as per windows XP and Ubuntu, a few day ago I have formatted my computer & install win 7 operating system, but I have formatted C: drive only (win xp on c: drive) but not uninstall Ubuntu, now I start computer but I can not find Ubuntu which is already installed!! I have not more idea for Ubuntu, please anyone tell me how I can find Ubuntu in my computer, My computer only show windows 7 operating system.

Answer (score 0):

How was your setup originally configured? Was XP and Ubuntu both on separate partitions on the same Drive?

I ask because if they were on the same drive and you formatted that drive then your ubuntu install would be wiped along with xp. When you format a drive you are not just wiping one partition (ie the one xp was on), but the whole thing. I think the only thing you can do if this is the case is to reinstall ubuntu. If there were valuable files on the ubuntu partition you could MAYBE get them back by following the steps [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/537590/how-to-get-these-files-back/537594#537594).But you would have to attempt this BEFORE installing a fresh ubuntu os.

You may also be able to repair your bootloader depending on your situation, but we will need more info to clarify

NB - Please answer the questions and clarify your OP before attempting any recovery so we have a better idea of your situation.